# How to generate a string of given length which contains English alphabets, numbers and Spaces?

Tags: java

I know `RandomStringUtils.random(4000, true, true)` will generate a string with alphabets and numbers. But,the generated string doesn't contain space. How can I get a string which contains space as well?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for all the different overloads of the `random()` method?  Please don't post such questions without reading the documentation first and explaining why that was not helpful.

Comment: By *"contains english alphabets"*, I assume you mean "contains *letters* from the english alphabet"? Do you want both uppercase and lowercase letters?

Comment: @Andreas It doesn't make a difference for my use case.

Comment: @Jim Garrison I read the doc for RandomStringUtils and it has a [random()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random-int-java.lang.String-) method which allows you to specify chars to choose from. Is there a way to use Re to achieve the task?

Comment: @PM77-1 I want the string to have spaces at random locations. Can you explain more about your solution?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Is there a way to use Re to achieve the task?"* If you just specify the chars to choose from as `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 "` (space at the end), you get what you want (add uppercase letters if needed).

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the random method is overloaded and supports what you want. For example in this way

```
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++)
        tmp.append(c);
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        tmp.append(c);
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) // if you wish upper case
        tmp.append(c);
    tmp.append(' ');
    char[] chars = tmp.toString().toCharArray();
    String s = RandomStringUtils.random(4000, chars);
    System.out.println(s);
```

If you will use this multiple times, make sure to store the char array and only calculate it once.

**EDIT:** Answer without for loops

```
char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
            's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
            'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
            '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' '
};
String s2 = RandomStringUtils.random(4000, chars);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though it works, it seems more verbose than it needs to be. Is there way to use Regular expressions so that 2 for loops can be avoided?

Comment: @Pavan_k_k You can use char[] chars = {'a','b','c','d' .... } or "abce...".toCharArray()

Comment: My concern is not specifically about for loops, but the verbosity.

Comment: you can define a string with all lowercases (or a single for loop doing that), perform += with .toUpper and finally add the numbers + space and then toCharArray. Regex does not support this, nor would it really be less verbose than that. However theses few lines in a function aren't to bad